# Reading composite type over TCP in Julia

Tags: types, tcp, type-conversion, julia

I am trying to send/receive a composite type over TCP. In order to do this I first create listener part :

```
using Sockets

# my-compiste-type
struct Signal
 min::Array{Float32,1}
 max::Array{Float32,1}
end

listener = listen(12345)
receiver = accept(listener)

read!(receiver, Ref()) # problem !!!
```

On the other hand, the sender part code :

```
using Sockets

# my-compiste-type
struct Signal
    min::Array{Float32,1}
    max::Array{Float32,1}
end

s = Signal(rand(0:1, 10), rand(0:1, 10))   # data to send 


client = connect(12345) # connecting to server side
write(client, Ref(s))
```

Now the problem occurs when I try to read `read!(receiver, Ref())` . If I write `read!(receiver, Ref(Signal)())` then I get segmentation fault and the program exits. And if I write `read!(receiver, Ref(typeof(Signal)())` then I get errors.

What is the right way to send composite data types from sender to receiver ?

I also found a similar question on [Julia discourse page](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/send-composite-type-over-tcp-udp/5233/7) but the o.p. solves the issue with UDPSocket. I also tried that but it uses `reinterpret` function. And reinterpret function does not convert Signal data type to UInt or other types.

Could you help please ?

B.R.

p.s. By the way I am using Julia version 1.0.3.

Comment: You might solve this with https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/

Comment: I am using Julia version 1.0.3. and methods in docs requires 1.1; 2 out of 3.

Comment: The serialize functions you need for this are available in 1.0.3. (the ones operating on filename have been added in 1.1)

Comment: thank you very much. Now resolved :)

Comment: Could you write your solution ? So I can give you a upvote :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your example, you can use Julia's native serialization capability:

#### Sending:

```
import Sockets, Serialization

struct Signal # my-compiste-type
    min::Array{Float32,1}
    max::Array{Float32,1}
end

s = Signal(rand(0:1, 10), rand(0:1, 10)) # data to send 
client = Sockets.connect(12345) # connecting to server side
s = Serialization.serialize(client, s) # serialize content
# ... remember to cleanup IO connections with close
```

#### Receiving

```
import Sockets, Serialization

struct Signal # my-compiste-type
    min::Array{Float32,1}
    max::Array{Float32,1}
end

listener = Sockets.listen(12345)    
receiver = Sockets.accept(listener)
s = Serialization.deserialize(receiver)
# ... remember to cleanup IO connections with close
```

Keep in mind:

- Julias native serialization will only work with equal system architecture and Julia version.
- If you need standardized protocols, you might have look at https://github.com/ExpandingMan/Arrow.jl